# Compare strings after Assert failed in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wrote a unit test for serializing XML files. It looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDeserialize()
{
    var appValue = Persister.ReadFromXml("before.xml");
    Persister.WriteToXml(appValue, "after.xml");

    var before = File.ReadAllText("before.xml");
    var after = File.ReadAllText("after.xml");
    Assert.AreEqual(before, after);
}
```

The test fails. Therefore I get a little window in the bottom left corner of Visual Studio 2015 that says:

> Message: Error at "Assert.AreEqual". Expected:<...> Actual:<...>

In Eclipse or IntelliJ, when I doubleclick on the test failure, the expected and actual value open in a diff editor so that I can quickly see where they differ.

Does Visual Studio offer a similar feature, or do I have to copy the text to the clipboard and manually extract the expected and actual value and then compare it in a text editor? The XML text is pretty long, therefore I’d like to get some help by the IDE.

Comment: If I understand you, people usually call this a "diffing tool", not a "compare editor". (I haven't used this functionality in either IDE.)

Comment: For an IDE-independent approach, you could make your own method that knows how to send the two strings to the user's diffing tool if you call a method in the immediate window. Something like `assertResult.OpenTool()`, which calls into VS's merge tool, or kdiff3, or whatever. Would that be helpful?

Comment: Xunit.net has better assertion failure messages, I'm sure it points out the first place there is a character difference in the message - not perfect, but better IMO :)

Answer (score -2):

In order to compare two strings using C#, I would suggest utilizing the `String.Equals` method.

```
public void TestDeserialize()
{
    var appValue = Persister.ReadFromXml("before.xml");
    Persister.WriteToXml(appValue, "after.xml");

    var before = File.ReadAllText("before.xml");
    var after = File.ReadAllText("after.xml");
    bool before_equals_after = before.Equals(after, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

For testing equality between other object types, see `IComparable`
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320727

Comment: I know how to compare strings. The purpose of my question is just to complain about the awful unit testing support built in into Microsoft Visual Studio.